# Problemas con mysql server

Tags: mysql, xampp

no me inicia el servicio de mysql server usando xampp cuando abro los logs tengo lo siguiente creo que debe ser problema de los usuarios que trae por defecto.

````
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-25 21:06:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 113854; transaction id 9
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200525 21:06:01
2020-05-25 21:06:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.```
````

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te muestra? en la parte del log que compartes no se muestra ningún error.

Comment: Borre todo el archivo de log y esa es la única información que me muestra, pero no me inicia

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo soluciones restaurando la ultima copia del backup